# Total Probability Rule: Continuous Case

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Can the total probability be applied to continuous distributions?

Suppose a random variable X with probability distribution $f_{X4}$. Suppose another random variable Y with probability distribution $f_Y$. Now if we partition $f_X$ into three regions, and obtain $f_Y | f_{X1}, f_Y | f_{X2}$, and $f_Y|f_{X3}$. Can we say:

$f_Y|f_X = (f_Y | f_{X1})P_{X1} + (f_Y | f_{X2})P_{X2} + (f_Y | f_{X3})P_{X3}$

where $P_{X1}$ = integral of $f_{X1}$ with the range of integral equal to limits of $f_{X1}$, and so on.

Comment: Can you use more standard notation? It's very hard to tell what you mean.

Comment: Yes, I assume you mean $\displaystyle f_Y(y) = \sum_{i=1}^n f_{Y|X\in A_i}(y)\Pr\{X \in A_i\}$, where the collection of $A_i$ forms a partition of $\mathbb{R}$, and $n$ is countable.

Comment: Hi Jack, the original post is now in a more standard notation thanks to callculus. Regarding my question, I am interested in applying total probability rule to the case of continuous distributions.

Comment: Hi BGM, Thanks for your answer. Collection of A_i indeed forms a partition of R. I just have a follow up question. Suppose I obtain another distribtion f_Y for random variable Y without considering its dependence on random variable X. Is there a way to tell how much additional information is available in f_Y obtained using its dependence on X as compared to f_Y obtained without considering dependence. Can I use the concepts of mutual information for this'